# Siri request only launching the app- not handling request

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I have implemented a siri extension in an app, I've included the intent in both the app plist as well as extension plist by defining the name of it in NSUserActivityTypes and NSExtension however when I try and run the intent- the app just opens and "application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:] has an interaction attached but it is not handled" is printed out in console.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you need to capture the activity and handle it within that method. Thats what the error is telling you. An NSUserActivity is being passed but not handled

Comment: @Scriptable I am also getting same message, I am developing using Xamarin.iOS, where I have to handle this activity? I have handled it inside ContinueUserActivity override method of AppDelegate

Comment: @Divyesh_08 i dont know any xarmarin so i cannot really help.